# Употребление "к примеру" по аналогии с "например"

Tags: вводные-слова

Следует ли по аналогии со словом "например" после сочетания "к примеру" ставить двоеточие, если за ним приводятся конкретные примеры?

Существуют различные типы голосов. К примеру: тенор, альт, баритон.

Comment: Если мы что-то перечисляем, то двоеточие можно ставить всегда.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) **Есть ли разница между *например* и *к примеру***

В толковом словаре Кузнецова разница не указывается: ***К примеру; к примеру сказать,*** в зн. вводн. словосочетания. ***=Например***.

**А что думают пользователи русского языка?** Они разное что думают. Чувствуют, что есть какая-то разница, да вот какая?

Послушаем?

Абсолютно никакой, они взаимозаменяемы. Единственный нюанс — *к примеру* звучит заметно более просторечиво. А мне кажется, что, наоборот, *например* — более "просторечивый" вариант. По Ожегову, *к примеру* — разговорный вариант, я бы не употреблял *к примеру* в письменной речи.

*Например* — употребляется при пояснении чего-то. Был, например, случай. 
*К примеру* — для примера.  К примеру, тебе нужно изменить цвет волос. Нет, вообще никакой разницы нет. Но *например* употребляют чаще, потому что его используют в разговорной речи как вводное слово.

Так как же быть, ***same*** или нет?

2) **Ответ на вопрос** (мнение обычного пользователя, но зато обоснованное)

***Существуют различные типы голосов. К примеру (сказать): тенор, альт, баритон.***

Нет, так не говорят, тут дело даже не в двоеточии.  Приведенное предложение некорректно, его нужно редактировать: ***Существуют различные типы голосов, например: тенор, альт, баритон.***

Здесь должно использоваться вводное слово ***например***, пояснительное двоеточие также обычно относится к этому слову, по крайней мере в книжной речи.

Почему? **Потому что сначала формулируется утверждение**, а потом приводятся поясняющие примеры к нему.

Сочетание ***к примеру*** используется, если **само утверждение приводится как пример.** В этом случае вводные сочетания ***например*** и ***к примеру*** взаимозаменяемы, но различаются по стилю (*к примеру* – разговорный вариант)

Пример: *Звучание определяется основным тоном и дополнительными звуками, именуемыми обертонами. **Например (к примеру)**, чем больше обертонов – тем ярче и красочнее будет голос.*

Answer (score 0):

Следует, так как его можно заменить на "например".

Но "к примеру" лучше употреблять при одном примере, а "например" - при любом количестве.

Главное то, что "к примеру" употребляется при какой-либо информации:
*К примеру, удобно за один день зафиксировать все поступления в одном документе.

Сегодня, к примеру, на обед давали кисель из смородины.

Ольга, к примеру, занимается плаванием.*

Розенталь отмечает, что "к примеру" указывает на связь мыслей, последовательность их изложения.

То есть "к примеру" и "например" сильно отличаются по употреблению.